# Formatting text in Python

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I currently have a breadcrumb package which have successfully deployed into my website. The package displays the name of the name of the html document which is gleamed from the web directory.

I'm still very new to Python.

This correctly display the breadcrumb trail, however I need to format this. My code is as follows but Django appears to ignore any formatting I tell it to action.

```
class BreadcrumbsItem:
def __init__(self, name_raw, path, position, base_url=None):
    .....
    self.remove_dashes = self.name_raw.replace("-", " ")
    ....

    def remove_dashes(self):
       formatted_path_name = str(name_raw)
       return formatted_path_name.replate("-"," ")
```

Why are the items (page names) in the breadcrumbs in my HTML document not being removed?

Comment: is `remove_dashes` meant to be a method or a value?

Answer (score 0):

There's some errors in your function, but if you want to run the function when the class gets instantiated, you'd need to call it.

```
    class BreadcrumbsItem:
        def __init__(self, name_raw, path, position, base_url=None):

            self.remove_dashes(name_raw)
```

Also note that `name_raw` is an argument passed to `BreadcrumbsItem` so you don't do `self.name_raw` because it's not part of the instance of the class.

So what you might want to do is provide a `name` for an instance of your class that's had the dashes replaced with spaces. That might work a bit like;

```
    class BreadcrumbsItem:
        def __init__(self, name_raw, path, position, base_url=None):
        
            self.name = self.remove_dashes(name_raw)

        def remove_dashes(self, name_raw):
           formatted_path_name = str(name_raw)
           return formatted_path_name.replace("-"," ")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Give up, Sick to death of this bullshit.